# Cisco 887w SDM Express Wizard freeze

Tags: cisco, router

I have a Cisco 877w router that I have reset. After trying a lot of different Java versions for the configuration applet (turns out the router uses a deprecated certificate that has been removed from latest Java versions - I got it working with Java 6 update 16) I finally got the Cisco SDM Express Wizard running.

After going through *Overview* -> *Basic configuration* -> *LAN IP Address* -> *DHCP* I should continue to the next section, *Internet (WAN)*, but when I click the Next button nothing happens and the wizard is stuck.

I do not have the router connected to an ADSL cable as I was hoping to be able to use one of the ethernet ports for WAN and the rest for LAN. If that is what is causing trouble I can instead use the telnet interface to configure the router, but I prefer the GUI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I have found a solution to the problem: by downgrading Java even further the wizard works like a charm. I'm now using [Java 6 update 10](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jre-6u10-oth-JPR) and everything seems to be working fine.